# Add Class to parent, jquery and IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, parent

So simple, but can't get this to work in IE9. Ive read tons of answers and nothing seems to work. I just need to add a class to an elements parent, seems simple right? In all other browsers, this does the trick:

```
$('#trigger').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass('bar');
});
```

Not in IE9. The solutions Ive found don't work either:

```
$('#trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = $(this).closest("li");
    $(item).addClass('bar');
});
```

[Here's a fiddle to try in IE9](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3km6rv/7/)

Answer (score 0):

This is working in IE9

```js
$('#trigger').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
   var item =$(this).parent('li');
    $(item).addClass('bar');
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="foo">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="trigger">click me</a>
    </li>
    <li>other shit</li>
</ul>
```